# Is there anyway to have a multi dimensional map?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm looking for a way to have a multi dimensional map in C++. It would be something like :

```
["Key1"]
         ["SubKey1"] = "Value"
         ["SubKey2"] = "Value"
["Key2"]
         ...
```

Comment: Alternatively, use `std::pair` as the key.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a

```
std::map<std::vector<std::string>, std::string>
```

Comment: Are you sure this will work? I didn't know vector has `operator <`